# Get values of dynamic fields with random ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where you can add input fields dynamically with jQuery.

```
<form class="test">
  1. <input type="text" class="title" id="title-1" placeholder="title">
  1. <input type="text" class="subtitle" id="subtitle-1" placeholder="title">
  <br />
  2. <input type="text" class="title" id="title-2" placeholder="subtitle">
  2. <input type="text" class="subtitle" id="subtitle-2" placeholder="subtitle">
</form>
<span class="addField">Add new fields</span>
```

```
var count=0; var arr=[] 
while(count< noOfFields){ 
  var id = '#title' + count; 
  var arr[count]=$(id).val(); 
  count++;
}
```

I want to get the  values of each pair of text fields (title/subtitle) and save them to a Mysql database. My question for this moment is: how to get the contents of the fields (with dynamic id) with jQuery?

Comment: You forgot to post the jQuery you tried.

Comment: `var count=0; var title=[]; var subtitle=[]; while(count< noOfFields/2){ tid = '#title-' + count; stid='#subtitle-' + count; title[count]=$(tid).val();
subtitle[count]=$(stid).val(); count++;}` . `noOfFields` will contain a count of text fields added dynamically.

Comment: I put your JQuery code to your question. Next time don't paste more than 1 line of code into comment, instead edit your question (you can do that at every time!). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use about each feature, which I have been looking all input and then comparing what they id

```
$(".test").find("input").each(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get values by using each value with selecting classes. code could be something like.

```
var arr1 = {};
$( ".title" ).each(function( index ) {
var arr1[index] = $( this ).val() ;
});
var arr2 = {};
$( ".subtitle" ).each(function( index ) {
var arr2[index]  = $( this ).val() ;
});
```

you will get all data within arr1 and arr2 inputs.